# When does the params hash get reset in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I googled this and wasn't able to get a clear answer from the top 5 hits.

When do the values in the params hash get reset in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are sent with every request, so they will be "reset" on every request.

Comment: To clarify, if a POST request is sent to /users/new, and the users controller then redirects_to sessions/new, that all counts as one request?

Comment: No. Redirecting is a new request.

Comment: @Logan Serman: It starts POST "/users/sign_in" since authentication fails again process by sessionscontroller#new but the parameters are still there? Does it not count as a separate request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430533/press-back-button-on-correct-sign-in-after-incorrect-sign-in-takes-to-the-signin?noredirect=1#comment45192648_28430533