# press back button on correct sign in after incorrect sign in takes to the signin page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise, and I m facing a interesting use case. Being at the page:
`http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`, if I enter the correct login id and password, I log into the site. Now, if I press back button, it says u are already logged in.

but Being at the page:
`http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`, I enter wrong login id and password, it gives error, and again remains at this page. I enter correct login id and password, I log into the site. Now, if I press back button, it takes to the login page.

How should I overcome this

Comment: I'd just redirect from the login page if they're logged in if that's what you want to do.

Comment: It doesn't go to the controller, since its on the press of the back button, how can i redirect?

Comment: The back button will load the sign in page, which will go to the user controller's sign in action.

Comment: Isn't the back button nothing more than "navigate history back" in the browser??? It doesn't care what might have gotten you to your current page. It's a simple, stupid "go back 1 page in browser history".  If the user chooses not to follow your happy path of application flow, you should not try to constrain them by fiddling with the browser history stack or overriding browser controls. It's the users browser, not yours.

Comment: And this is why i m not following other posts that says to clear the cache, but i m quite surprised on the behavior,as to why when after correct login credentials the very first time, the back button does not take them to the login page, whereas incorrect, then correct then back does so..

Comment: What's the controller code for the failed login case? A difference between render and redirect? (Don't know what your controller is doing in the success versus failure cases).